# How to add observer on a UISlider

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Any idea how can i add my controller class as a observer for my View class' slider?

I am trying to achieve this via Observer way: Inside my controller's viewDidLoad method I am calling

```
[self addObserver:myView forKeyPath:@"myView.mySlider.value" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

and in the same controller file i am implementing:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context { 
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myView.mySlider.value"]) {
        myView.myImgView.animationDuration = [[change valueForKey:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew] intValue]; 
    } 
}
```

But my app is crashing. Please help

Comment: Do you get any error messages when the app is crashing? :)

Comment: Please edit the stack trace and any Debugger Console output into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem. I was setting the observer wrongly. Instead of calling the addObserver method on self i am supposed to call it on the object which i need to observe.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the slider to an `IBAction`as you would do with a button. The action is called whenever the slider changes its value.
If you need to be notified in another class of changed slider values, send a `NSNotification` in your `IBAction` and register for that notification in other classes.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this via Observer way:
Inside my controller's viewDidLoad method I am calling
[self addObserver:myView forKeyPath:@"myView.mySlider.value" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
and in the same controller file i am implementing:
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myView.mySlider.value"]) {
  myView.myImgView.animationDuration = [[change valueForKey:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew] intValue];
  
 }
}

But my app is crashing. Please help.

Comment: Inside my controller viewDidLoad==>
[self addObserver:myView forKeyPath:@"myView.mySlider.value" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

==== Inside my view controller class ===>

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
 if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myView.mySlider.value"]) {
  myView.myImgView.animationDuration = [[change valueForKey:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew] intValue];
 }
}

Comment: I am not able to put the code in the readable format when adding comments :( ... sorry about that

Comment: Abhinav: Moreover, it appears to just repeat the question. There is no need to do that.